# pandas filter rows based on row 1 column B equals row 2 column A and so forth

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have a problem that I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish.
I have a dataframe with multiple columns containing names and hrs.

```
d = {'ID': [1, 2,3,4,5,6], 'uName': ['Mark', 'Joe', 'Patty', 'Mary', 'Ted', 'Sam'], 'sName': ['Patty','Mary', 'Sam','Sally','Tony','Bob'], 'hrs': [20, 16,35,18,15,21], 'dep': ['A', 'J', 'K','I','P','U']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to select a row, in this example I'll select Row 1 Mark, I then want to take the sName and select the next row where sName in this row is equal to pName in the new row , so in this I would use Patty and select row 3. I would then take Sam and select row 6 since Sam is the uName in row 6 and since there are no others where Bob is in uName I would end

```
ID   uName   sName   hrs   dep
1    Mark    Patty    20    A
2    Joe     Mary     16    J
3    Patty    Sam     35    K
4    Mary    Sally    18    I
5    Ted      Tony    15    P
6    Sam      Bob     21    U
```

so my new df would be

```
ID   uName   sName   hrs   dep
1    Mark    Patty    20    A
3    Patty    Sam     35    K
6    Sam      Bob     21    U
```

Almost thinking networkx may be a good solution here, but not sure. Figured I would see if anyone knows how in pandas to do this. I am only using a few examples here, but my real data has around 90k rows

Answer (score 2):

Lets use `networkx` to find all the `descendents` of `Mark` then use `isin` to filter the rows

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'uName', 'sName', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
nodes = nx.descendants(G, 'Mark')

df.loc[df['sName'].isin(nodes)]
```

Result

```
   ID  uName  sName  hrs dep
0   1   Mark  Patty   20   A
2   3  Patty    Sam   35   K
5   6    Sam    Bob   21   U
```

Comment: Neat, but doesn't this solution rely on every `sName` entry only occurring at most once as a `uName` entry, and if so, only in a later row? If `sName` in last row was _Joe_, rows 2 and 4 would also be selected. It's not abundantly clear but I took _...take the sName and select the next row where sName in this row is equal to pName in the new row..._ to mean that you only look forward and only take one descendant. But example data set lacking any instances of duplicated `uName`s or name occurring in `sName` before `uName` does hint that we don't need to worry about duplicates or ordering.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see a way to avoid looping through rows to include. If that is taken as a given, pandas part of the problem boils down to efficiently identifying next row. Two approaches - and I do not know pandas well enough to say which is the better, but here ordered according to my best guess - are

- Use groupby to split into sets of rows with same `uName` and search for next higher index in group of current row's `sName`
- Exclusive utilise index searching, but on a `MultiIndex` made from `uName` and original index; thing to note is that `Index.searchsorted` doesn't seem to work for a `MultiIndex`, so need to use `Index.get_indexer` instead

Core idea in both cases is that row `i` triggers selection of first row in slice `df.loc[(df["sName"][i], i+1):]` if `df` had sorted index made of `uName` and original row numbers. But without actually creating that slice.

Implementations, as generators producing indexes from `DataFrame` selected - and both assume that the original `DataFrame` has a `0..n-1` index:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
     'uName': ['Mark', 'Joe', 'Patty', 'Mary', 'Ted', 'Sam'],
     'sName': ['Patty','Mary', 'Sam','Sally','Tony','Bob'],
     'hrs': [20, 16, 35, 18, 15, 21],
     'dep': ['A', 'J', 'K', 'I', 'P', 'U']
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def groupby(df):
    names = df.groupby("uName")
    name, i = df.at[0, "uName"], 0
    try:
        while True:
            yield i
            # Get subset of rows with next name as uName
            name = df.at[i, "sName"]
            g = names.get_group(name)
            # Find location of next larger row index in subset and get this index
            i = g.index[g.index.searchsorted(i+1)]
    except (KeyError, IndexError):
        # Either name is not in uName, or all occurrences are prior to row i
        pass
print(df.loc[[i for i in groupby(df)]])

def indexsearch(df):
    # Create sorted MultiIndex of uName and df index
    s = df.reset_index().set_index(["uName", "index"])["sName"].sort_index()
    name = df.at[0, "uName"]
    i = s.index.get_indexer([(name, 0)])[0]
    while i >= 0:
        yield s.index[i][1]
        name = s.iat[i]
        # Find location in s of name with higher index than current index
        i = s.index.get_indexer([(name, i+1)], method="bfill")[0]
        if s.index[i][0] != name:
            # Either no location was found, or location has wrong name
            #  (name not found beyond current row)
            i = -2
print(df.loc[[i for i in indexsearch(df)]])
```